# when i restart my emulator i cannot retrieve database values in sqlite windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I designed a login and registration page using Sqlite database in windows phone 8.1. With the following code I can successfully insert and retrieve the values from sqlite database. But it happens only once. When I restart my emualator I cannot retrieve the values from database.

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/ebook.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
        await con.CreateTableAsync<Register>();
    }
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/ebook.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
        await con.CreateTableAsync<Register>();
        Register m = new Register();

        m.Name = text_reg.Text;
        m.Password = text_password.Password;
        string rd = "";
        if (radio_male.IsChecked == true)
        {
            rd = "Male";

        }
        else
        {
            rd = "Female";

        }
        m.Gender = rd;
        m.State = ((ComboBoxItem)combo_box.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();


        await con.InsertAsync(m);

        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("success");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/ebook.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        Register t = new Register();
        string query = string.Format("select Name,Password from Register where Name='{0}' and Password='{1}'", text_user.Text, text_pass.Password);
        List<Register> mylist = await con.QueryAsync<Register>(query);
        if (mylist.Count == 1)
        {
            t = mylist[0];
        }

        if (t.Name == text_user.Text && t.Password == text_pass.Password)
        {

            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
        else
        {
            var messagedialog = new MessageDialog("Unsuccessful").ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. State isn't persisted in the Windows Phone emulator. When you restart it, it loses all the data you previously stored (settings, installed applications, and whatever you wrote on the storage).

This won't occur on an actual, physical device.